# "Unable to locate package" for exa on WSL 2 Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install [exa](https://the.exa.website/) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL 2. Whenever I type `sudo apt install exa`, I get this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package exa
```

I saw that the [apt repository for exa](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/exa) is `universe`, so I ran `sudo add-apt-repository universe` but it says:

```
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

I've been able to install other packages like `docker` just fine using `apt install`. I'm still super new to Linux in general, so any help would be appreciated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The *groovy* name is 20.10, not 20.04 LTS. So [this package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rust-exa/0.9.0-4) is not available for 20.04 LTS.

But you can install it manually with:

```
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rust-exa/exa_0.9.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./exa_0.9.0-4_amd64.deb
```

and test it via:

> ```
> $ exa --version
> exa v0.9.0
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you get that URL from? Also, my processor is Intel x64 - why is the file named `...amd64.deb`?

Comment: Such URL are found using search on https://packages.ubuntu.com , from the [rust-exa download page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/exa/download).

Comment: amd64 means it is for 64 bit architecture that was designed by AMD back then

Comment: When installing, I get this:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ``exa : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.32) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.``

Comment: @JaberAlNahian Please be more specific. I have just tested above method on fresh 20.04 LTS docker container. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: You can use https on the wget line for better security, no need to pull down packages unsecurely